# Would somebody have an example of how-to use and program a Spring PathMatchConfigurer?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Would somebody have example code which shows how-to use and program a Spring PathMatchConfigurer?

Comment: [Link1](http://java.dzone.com/articles/spring-3-webmvc-optional-path)
[Link2](http://scottfrederick.cfapps.io/blog/2011/03/11/Customizing-Spring-3-mvc-annotation-driven) might help you

Comment: yes link1  fits perfectly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`PathMatchConfigurer` helps with configuring `HandlerMappings` path matching options such as trailing slash match, suffix registration, path matcher and path helper. Configured path matcher and path helper instances are shared for:

```
`RequestMappings`
`ViewControllerMappings`
`ResourcesMappings`
```

for the Spring '[PathMatchConfigurer](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.1.0.RC1/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/PathMatchConfigurer.html)', example follow [this](http://java.dzone.com/articles/spring-3-webmvc-optional-path)

Comment: Last link is dead

Answer (score 0):

Configure the `PathMatchConfigurer` like this, eg to remove the semi-colon restriction:

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configurePathMatch(PathMatchConfigurer configurer) {
      var urlPathHelper = new UrlPathHelper();
      urlPathHelper.setRemoveSemicolonContent(false);
      configurer.setUrlPathHelper(urlPathHelper);
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that the `org.springframework.security.web.firewall.StrictHttpFirewall` will reject semicolons and other characters as well:

```
@Bean
public StrictHttpFirewall httpFirewall() {
    StrictHttpFirewall firewall = new StrictHttpFirewall();
    firewall.setAllowSemicolon(true);
    return firewall;
}
```